# Raise a event in the UserControl and listening on it in the mainwindow

Tags: .net, wpf, events, event-handling, code-behind

I have a UserControl A.

In the code behind file I want to raise a particular event (created by me).

Now I want that the Main Window (which contains the user control) is listening to the event.

In WindowsForms i used this way:

```
namespace MyProgramm
{
    public partial class MyClass
    {   
        public MyClass()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
        }

        internal event MyEventHandler MyEvent;

        private void RaiseMyEvent()
        {
            if (MyEvent!= null)
            {
                MyEvent(this, ...);
            }
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }

    }

    internal delegate void MyEventHandler (MyClass sender, ...);
}
```

How can I solve this in a nice way in WPF?

Comment: Exactly the same way, except that the `internal` declarations should perhaps also be `public`, and you should consider using [EventHandler<TEventArgs>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db0etb8x.aspx) instead of your own event handler type. Where is your problem?

Comment: @Clemens I have no problem, I just wanted to ask if there is another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, nicer would by to use [EventHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db0etb8x.aspx) instead of your own delegate type.

Also, if the class is public and has a public constructor, you might make `MyEvent` public.

```
public event EventHandler<MyEventArgs> MyEvent;
```